# Moduli potential in Type IIB String Theory

Tags: moduli, string-theory

In the book *String Theory and M-Theory* by K. Becker, M. Becker and J.H. Schwarz:

1. Why is the potential for moduli given by eq (10.168): 
   $$\tag{10.168 }V(T,K) ~=~ \frac1{4\mathcal{V}^3} \Big( \int_{CY_4} F \wedge \star F - \frac16 \chi T_{M2} \Big)?$$
   Maybe the answer of this question is trivial, but I cannot see how $T$ and $K$ enter this picture and get $V(T,K)$ as their potential.
2. How can one arrives at eq (10.181): 
   $$\tag{10.181} V~=~e^{\mathcal{K}} \Big( G^{a \bar{b}} \mathcal{D}_a W \mathcal{D}_\bar{b} \bar{W} - 3|W|^2 \Big)?$$

Comment: For 2) I find some hints in the book :  [Supergravity](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/physics/theoretical-physics-and-mathematical-physics/supergravity) : Formulae (17.45),(17.84),(17.128),(17.129),(17.131) (17.134). It is totally beyond my skills, but the idea is to make a link between embedding Kalhler manifold with conformal symmetry , with projective Kahler manifolds for physical fields (Superpoincaré gravity). So the scalar potential is calculated from the metrics and the superpotential on the embedding manifold, which have relations with $K$ and $W$.